# Use MAX and MIN in Bindingless operations

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

So I have read the ecto documentation for Bindingless operations. They are great for dynamic values.

```
from Post,
  where: [category: "fresh and new"],
  order_by: [desc: :published_at],
  select: [:id, :title, :body]
```

So my question is. Is there any way we can use `max` or `min` in the above like this:

```
 select: max[:some_field]
```

I tried it but it's not working.

If anyone suggests any method how to use it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ecto provides [`Ecto.Query.API.max/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#max/1) for bound values.

For bindingless operations, one should stick to [`Ecto.Query.API.fragment/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#fragment/1):

```
fragment("max(?)", :some_field)
```